# How to reuse code/functionality from multiple Spring Boot applications?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reusability

I'm developing multiple applications (API's) with Spring Boot and some of them are only used by some specific clients. The problem is that I'm having to duplicate code and functionalities between different API's and I don't know how to reuse the code in them.

For an example, I have a main API that every client use and it has multiple model/dto/services/controller. I have another API that's specific for one client (which I don't want to have in my main API, because some clients won't need it) that needs some of the main API entities.

Should I unify the applications and find a way to separate them inside one project, or how could I reuse these entities between the different applications?

Is creating a library with the main models, dtos, exceptions the best solution here?

One question I have with creating a library is, when I'm developing one API that uses this library, I have to have the library compiled? or it can use a non-compiled version?

I'm asking this because it could make the development process more slow for the team (if we have to recompile every time we make a change in the library).

Haven't tried anything yet

Answer (score 1):

Library is your best bet in this situation and you'll have to compile it in order to share it accross the different APIs (assuming that by this you mean different projects and repos). The code needs to be compiled and then shared as a maven/gradle shared library so you can import it in other services that are being developed. 
If you're looking to test something fast, you can always deploy a test/dev version of the library and use that for local testing/developing until the feature is ready and then update the latest version of the library. Keep in mind that this also prevents you from forcing changes to other repos, since they can always use the old library version, until they're ready to update (use semantic versioning).